# Split doesn't explode on comma

Tags: c#

Im trying to split a String into an Array. In PHP I normally use explode -> profit. But I cant get it to work in C# ...

```
string fuel = "08,02,22,97,38,15";
string[] numbers = fuel.Split(new char[] { ',' });
```

He just splits on every character, fe: numbers[0]=0 and numbers[1]=8

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I used the fuel string as fuel[0] which gives the first char, hence the mistake. It shouldve been numbers[0] stupid mistake!

Comment: I executed your code and it works fine.

Comment: Just copied and pasted your example code, and it worked fine - got a string array with 6 entries as expected.

Comment: This works just fine for me.  numbers[0] == "08"

Comment: Are you sure you looked at `numbers[0]` and `numbers[1]` and not `fuel[0]` and `fuel[1]`? (`string` implements an indexer that returns the separate characters within the string)

Comment: instead of new char[] { ',' } try just ','

Comment: Are you sure you're not doing fuel[0] and fuel[1] as they would give the results indicated.

Comment: GRAAAA @DavidGouge and Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks guys. You solved this abomination :D I was focussing too much on the Split function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here - look at this http://ideone.com/dYxaa

Answer (score 0):

try this: `fuel.Split(',');`

Ain't c# great ;)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have works fine. It can be further simplified to:

```
string fuel = "08,02,22,97,38,15";
string[] numbers = fuel.Split(',');
```

Are you sure what you have pasted is the code that is failing?

Answer (score 0):

I've just run this code and it does as you expect

Are you sure you haven't got something like numbers[0][0] and  numbers[0][1]?